# Extract a substring in HTML tags by using Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am trying to extract a substring from a fragment of HTML code like this:

```
some text here. some text here.<img src="//zhihu.com/equation?tex=m_%7Bt%2B1%7D" alt="m_{t+1}" eeimg="1">some text here.<img src="//zhihu.com/equation?tex=p_t%3DE_t%28m_%7Bt%2B1%7Dx_%7Bt%2B1%7D%29" alt="p_t=E_t(m_{t+1}x_{t+1})" eeimg="1">some text here.
```

To draw substring `m_{t+1}` contained in the first `img` tag and `p_t=E_t(m_{t+1}x_{t+1})` in the second tag, I just use a regexp `<img.+ alt="((?!eeimg).)*" eeimg="1">` in Notepad++, but the expression does not match the the two `img` tags seperately, it just shows a result which contains the whole HTML fragment.

Can anyone show me a correct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make .+ non-greedy adding ? to it like this:

```
(<img(.+?) alt="((?!eeimg).)*" eeimg="1">)
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, It is exactly the one I expect.

Comment: What are you replacing this regex with?